# How to go from Medan International Airport to Medan city center?

Tags: budget, airports, airport-transfer, indonesia, kno

I want to go to [Medan city center (Indonesia)](https://www.google.com.sg/maps/place/Medan,+Medan+City,+North+Sumatra,+Republic+of+Indonesia/@2.7016627,101.5396721,7z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x303131cc1c3eb2fd:0x23d431c8a6908262) when arriving by plane at [Medan International airport (called Kualanamu International Airport).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kualanamu_International_Airport)

Can I take a public bus? A tuk tuk? A rickshaw? A taxi?

If you have info on the prices (interesting for travellers on a budget) that'd be great too.

Comment: Much to far for a rickshaw (which is called *becak* in indonesia, in case you want to ask for one) unless you arrive at  the old polonia airport which is located more or less in the heart of the city.

Answer (score 4):

#### Your Options Include Airport Train, Airport Shuttle, Buses, Taxis, and Renting a Car

[The Kualanamu airport website has a page dedicated to airport transfer information.](http://www.kualanamu-airport.co.id/en/guides/transportation) Several options are listed there along with the approximate prices for each solution. [Being the first Sumatran airport to be directly linked to the city centre via rail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kualanamu_International_Airport), I think the Airport Train might be a good solution to reach Medan city. According to the linked website the cost of a train ride is (as of November 15th (I'm assuming) 2014) 80.000`Rp`. Buying several tickets at once entitles you to proportionally discounted fares. Below is a screenshot of the linked website with more information on the Airport train:

[image: Airport train info screenshot]

More information can be found on [the website of Railink the company managing the trains](http://www.railink.co.id). For completeness sake, your other options are buses, Airport shuttle, taxis and renting a car.

Answer (score 2):

The airport is about 16km from the city center.

---

The information below is from **May 2015**

Options I know of:

- Public bus: charges 20'000 IDR, it takes about 45min.
- Taxi: charges circa 150'000 IDR

---

#### Resources

http://www.virtualtourist.com/travel/Asia/Indonesia/North_Sumatra_Province/Medan-1213225/Transportation-Medan-TG-C-1.html

Answer (score 1):

The best  and  cheapest option is a public bus, the Perum Damri bus.
The last bus departs at 12pm to Medan city.